# Is there a way to return an output of a bool 'Yes' and 'No' with float values in a table format?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a need to return multiple code results in a row-by-column format. The code returns yes and no with float values. I want the float values to be categorized under 'yes' and 'No' columns and the rows will contain the target variables. So the end result should look something like this:

### Table Name: Attrition Rate by Department

| Department | Yes | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sales | 20.00 | 80.00 |

Here is the code I wrote for this. I need to input its result into the table format above.

```
sales_attr=round(((emp_data[emp_data['dept']=='sales']['attrition'].value_counts(['yes']))*100),2)
print("Sales Dept Attrition Rate: {0} %\n".format(sales_attr))
```

The output I get comes like this:

Sales Dept Attrition Rate:
no     75.51
yes    24.49

Name: attrition, dtype: float64 %

Python Ver: 3.9.12

P:S. This is my first python project, looking forward to your replies.

Thanks

Comment: I also tried to add percentage sign(%) on the float output using the "Print" function in the above code, but it did not show  where I wanted it to.  is there a better way to present this?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example